# Is it possible to verify the apple app site association file was properly requested and configured for an instance of an installed IOS app?

Tags: ios, branch.io, ios-universal-links, apple-app-site-associate, apple-app-site-association

**Is it possible to verify the apple app site association file was properly requested and configured for an instance of an installed IOS app?** Ideally, we could easily verify that Universal Links are working properly for an instance of a device and installed application for the purpose of debugging. As an alternative, we could leverage a metric that confirms this association occurred properly for the purpose of alarming.

#### Background

Clicking on a URL associated with an IOS application that has been properly configured [Universal Links enabled](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/General/Conceptual/AppSearch/UniversalLinks.html) **sometimes** does not immediately launch the associated app.

I am aware that there are a few known cases where the app does not launch when it should (eg. Source App use redirect URL for attribution, Association files fail to load etc), but it is not clear at a glance if this behavior is an actual widespread issue and it is not clear how to debug it.

#### What I have tried?

- Followed all steps listed for [Support Universal Links](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/General/Conceptual/AppSearch/UniversalLinks.html) to ensure Universal Links are properly configured
- Verified URL host with [Branch.io AASA Validator](https://branch.io/resources/aasa-validator/)
- Confirmed there is **no Web Server errors when serving these AASA files** from /.well-known/apple-app-site-association
- Confirmed this behavior works **most of the time***

*As an alternative to debugging, we have considered a metric that confirms this association (if it exists)